# Calculate distance from one point to the others by R

Tags: r, distance

I would like to calculate the distance from just one point to the others. From the matrix below, you can see that the distance from all points is being calculated concurrently. But I would like only one point to the rest. How do I define this in the formula? I would like, for example, to know the distance from property 6 to 19 other properties, so we would have only one line.

```
library(geosphere)
df<-structure(list(Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,  -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, 
+ -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9), Longitude = c(-49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.7, 
+ -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6), Production = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 175, 175, 350, 350, 175, 350, 175, 175, 364, 
+ 175, 175, 350, 45.5, 54.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
coordinaties<-df[,1:2]
d<-as.dist(distm(coordinaties[,2:1]))
data.matrix(d)

    1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8
1      0.00     0.00 11075.61 11075.61 11075.61 11075.61 11075.61 11075.61
2      0.00     0.00 11075.61 11075.61 11075.61 11075.61 11075.61 11075.61
3  11075.61 11075.61     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
4  11075.61 11075.61     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
5  11075.61 11075.61     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
6  11075.61 11075.61     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
7  11075.61 11075.61     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
8  11075.61 11075.61     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
9  11075.61 11075.61     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
10 11075.61 11075.61     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
11 15048.01 15048.01 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02
12 15048.01 15048.01 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02
13 15048.01 15048.01 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02
14 15048.01 15048.01 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02
15 15048.01 15048.01 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02
16 11075.61 11075.61     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
17 11075.61 11075.61     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
18 11075.61 11075.61     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
19 11075.61 11075.61     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
          9       10       11       12       13       14       15       16
1  11075.61 11075.61 15048.01 15048.01 15048.01 15048.01 15048.01 11075.61
2  11075.61 11075.61 15048.01 15048.01 15048.01 15048.01 15048.01 11075.61
3      0.00     0.00 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02     0.00
4      0.00     0.00 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02     0.00
5      0.00     0.00 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02     0.00
6      0.00     0.00 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02     0.00
7      0.00     0.00 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02     0.00
8      0.00     0.00 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02     0.00
9      0.00     0.00 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02     0.00
10     0.00     0.00 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02     0.00
11 10183.02 10183.02     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00 10183.02
12 10183.02 10183.02     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00 10183.02
13 10183.02 10183.02     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00 10183.02
14 10183.02 10183.02     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00 10183.02
15 10183.02 10183.02     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00 10183.02
16     0.00     0.00 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02     0.00
17     0.00     0.00 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02     0.00
18     0.00     0.00 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02     0.00
19     0.00     0.00 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02     0.00
         17       18       19
1  11075.61 11075.61 11075.61
2  11075.61 11075.61 11075.61
3      0.00     0.00     0.00
4      0.00     0.00     0.00
5      0.00     0.00     0.00
6      0.00     0.00     0.00
7      0.00     0.00     0.00
8      0.00     0.00     0.00
9      0.00     0.00     0.00
10     0.00     0.00     0.00
11 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02
12 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02
13 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02
14 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02
15 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02
16     0.00     0.00     0.00
17     0.00     0.00     0.00
18     0.00     0.00     0.00
19     0.00     0.00     0.00
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you provide more details when you meed one point to the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `?distm`: you can use two sets of points:

```
distm(coordinaties[6,2:1],coordinaties[-6,2:1])

         [,1]     [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]    [,10]    [,11]    [,12]
[1,] 11075.61 11075.61    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 10183.02 10183.02 10183.02
        [,13]    [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18]
[1,] 10183.02 10183.02     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Thank you very much Denis! Helped me a lot.

Comment: Happy to help! Don't forget to have a look at the help, there is most of the time the info you need